# Markov chain: if $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$, then why is $Z\rightarrow Y\rightarrow X$ true?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

in a Markov chain, given three random variables $X,Y,Z$, we have $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$, which means $p(x,y,z) = p(x)p(y|x)p(z|y)$.

The right arrow symbol $\rightarrow$ is used to denote a relationship of (in)dependence between the two variables, so that if $X\rightarrow Y$, it means that whatever value $Y$ has, this has no influence on the distribution of $X$, while the value of $X$ has an influence on the distribution of $Y$.

my textbook *Elements of Information Theory*, in section 2.8 (page 34) gives this statement without a demonstration: $Z\rightarrow Y\rightarrow X$

is that always true? How can this be demonstrated? Or, do you have any intuitive explanation?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what the $\to$ symbol means here?  I don't know what you mean by $p(x,y,z)$.  A common meaning for $x \to y$ is "starting from $x$, there is a positive probability of eventually reaching $y$".  If that's the meaning, then $x \to y \to z$ does not imply $z \to y \to x$ without further assumptions (for example, $z$ could be absorbing).  By the way, what is your textbook?

Comment: $p(x,y,z)$ is meant to be the joint probability of random variables $X,Y,Z$. $Z\rightarrow Y\rightarrow X$ is just stated to be a direct consequence of $X\rightarrow Y\rightarrow Z$, without any further assumption. Textbook *Elements of Information Theory*,  section 2.8 (page 34).

Comment: Ok, so I don't think this question really has anything to do with Markov chains.

Comment: Why do you think so? This is all about Markov chains, also the section in book I am ready is all about Markov chains. And $X \rightarrow  Y \rightarrow Z$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: @NateEldredge : check this out: http://www1.ece.uic.edu/~devroye/courses/ECE534/lectures/ch2.pdf on page 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow  Z$, we know that $X,Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$. The reverse chain, $Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow  X$, follows from the symmetry of that independence:

\begin{eqnarray*}
p(x,y,z) &=& p(x \mid y,z)\;p(y \mid z)\;p(z) \qquad\text{by the Chain Rule} \\
&=&p(x \mid y)\;p(y \mid z)\;p(z) \qquad\text{by conditional independence of $X,Z$ given $Y$}.
\end{eqnarray*}

As with Equation 2.117, where $\;p(x,y,z) = p(x)\;p(y \mid x)\;p(z \mid y)\;$ implies $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow  Z$ , the result above implies $Z \rightarrow Y \rightarrow  X$.